# How to place GUI object at specific x/y place within cell within GridBagLayout

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager, gridbaglayout

I'm new to Java Swing and am doing a small project to help me get familiar to use it. I'm trying to specify the placement dimensions of my objects (and their sizes), but I can't seem to get it right. I have the Object sizes presenting correct, but can't place them where I want. Below is an example of what it currently looks like, and what I'm looking for...

Currently...

[image]

Need to make it look like...

[image]

Below is the code I drummed up...

```
package Main;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.Border;
import javax.swing.border.TitledBorder;

import org.apache.commons.lang3.ArrayUtils;

public class StartGui extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

    private static final String[] GuiCharSelDefault = {"---  Select Character ---"};
    private static final int unselectedDefaultElement = 0;
    private static final String[] GuiCharSel = (String[])ArrayUtils.addAll(GuiCharSelDefault, Calculator.Characters);
    private String[] lvlRange = SupportMethods.createArrRange("- -", 1, 99);

    /*
     * Interactive GUI Objects
     */
    JLabel charPic;
    JComboBox charSelCombo = new JComboBox(GuiCharSel);
    JComboBox pickLvlAns = new JComboBox(lvlRange);
    JLabel nextLvlAns = new JLabel("- -");


    public StartGui() {
        /*
         * Non-Interactive GUI Objects
        */
        JPanel topFrame = new JPanel();
        JPanel bottomFrame = new JPanel();
        JPanel selPane = new JPanel();
        JLabel pickLvl = new JLabel("Pick Current Level:");
        JLabel nextLvl = new JLabel("Next Level:");

        //*******************************************************************************

        /*
         * Top Frame Settings
         */
        TitledBorder topFrameTitle;
        Border blackLine = BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black);
        Border raisedBevel = BorderFactory.createRaisedBevelBorder();
        Border loweredBevel = BorderFactory.createLoweredBevelBorder();
        Border compound = BorderFactory.createCompoundBorder(raisedBevel, loweredBevel);
        topFrameTitle = BorderFactory.createTitledBorder(compound, "Character");
        topFrameTitle.setTitleJustification(TitledBorder.CENTER);
        topFrame.setBorder(topFrameTitle);
        topFrame.setLayout(new BoxLayout(topFrame, BoxLayout.X_AXIS));


        /*
         * Adds Character Picture
         */
        charPic = new JLabel("", null, JLabel.CENTER);
        charPic.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100,100));
        topFrame.add(charPic);

        //*******************************************************************************

        /*
        * Selection Pane Settings
        */
        selPane.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        selPane.setBorder(blackLine);

        /*
        * Adds Character Selection ComboBox
        */
        charSelCombo.setPrototypeDisplayValue(charSelCombo.getItemAt(unselectedDefaultElement));
        selPane.add(charSelCombo, setGbc(0,0, "WEST", 0, 1, setInsets(0, 10, 0, 0)));

        /*
        * Adds "Pick Current Level:" Label
        */
        selPane.add(pickLvl, setGbc(0,1, "EAST", 0, 1, setInsets(0, 0, 0, 0)));

        /*
        * Adds "Next Level:" Label
        */
        selPane.add(nextLvl, setGbc(0,2, "EAST", 0, 1, setInsets(0, 0, 0, 0)));

        /*
        * Adds Character Current Level ComboBox
        */
        pickLvlAns.setPrototypeDisplayValue(pickLvlAns.getItemAt(lvlRange.length - 1));
        selPane.add(pickLvlAns, setGbc(1,1, "WEST", 1, 1, setInsets(0, 10, 0, 0)));

        /*
        * Adds Character Next Level Label
        */
        selPane.add(nextLvlAns, setGbc(1,2, "WEST", 1, 1, setInsets(0, 23, 0, 0)));

        //*******************************************************************************

        /*
         * BOTTOM PANE
         */
        TitledBorder bottomFrameTitle;
        bottomFrameTitle = BorderFactory.createTitledBorder(compound, "Stats");
        bottomFrameTitle.setTitleJustification(TitledBorder.CENTER);
        bottomFrame.setBorder(bottomFrameTitle);

        //*******************************************************************************

        /*
         * Display everything in GUI to user
         */
        add(topFrame, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        add(bottomFrame,BorderLayout.CENTER);

        setSize(800,600);
        setVisible(true);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
        String charName = ((JComboBox)(arg0.getSource())).getSelectedItem().toString();
        String image = "../images/"+charName+".png";
        charPic.setIcon(new ImageIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource(image)).getImage().getScaledInstance(100, 100, Image.SCALE_SMOOTH)));
        charSelCombo.removeItem(GuiCharSel[unselectedDefaultElement]);
        pickLvlAns.removeItem(lvlRange[unselectedDefaultElement]);
    }

    private GridBagConstraints setGbc(int gridx, int gridy, String anchorLocation, double weightx, double weighty, Insets insets){
        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();

        if (anchorLocation.toUpperCase().equals("NORTHWEST")){
            gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.NORTHWEST;
        } else if (anchorLocation.toUpperCase().equals("NORTH")){
            gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.NORTH;
        } else if (anchorLocation.toUpperCase().equals("NORTHEAST")){
            gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.NORTHEAST;
        } else if (anchorLocation.toUpperCase().equals("WEST")){
            gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;
        } else if (anchorLocation.toUpperCase().equals("EAST")){
            gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.EAST;
        } else if (anchorLocation.toUpperCase().equals("SOUTHWEST")){
            gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.SOUTHWEST;
        } else if (anchorLocation.toUpperCase().equals("SOUTH")){
            gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.SOUTH;
        } else if (anchorLocation.toUpperCase().equals("SOUTHEAST")){
            gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.SOUTHEAST;
        } else {
            gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.CENTER;
        }

        gbc.gridx = gridx;
        gbc.gridy = gridy;
        gbc.weightx = weightx;
        gbc.weighty = weighty;
        gbc.insets = insets;

        return gbc;
    }

    private Insets setInsets(int top, int left, int bottom, int right){
        Insets insets = new Insets(top,left,bottom,right);
        return insets;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new StartGui();
    }
}
```

If anyone could tell me if there is a way to do this, it would really help a alot

**Edit:** With the help from MadProgrammer, I did some tweaking to the code above which actually made it work.

Comment: The first thing you need to learn about laying out components in a modern GUI is, you don't control the position or size of the components. Pixel perfect layouts are an illusion, there are many factors that go into calculating the appropriate size and relationship of components, this is why there is a whole academic field dedicated to it. Instead, you supply hints and other properties which affect how the components are positioned.

Comment: With a `GridBagLayout` you can control many of the properties, including the additional size which is added to the component (ipad), how the component is anchored within the cell (alignment), how it fills and spans other cells and padding (insets) added around the component. You haven't already done so, I suggest having a read of [How to Use GridLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/grid.html)

Comment: The first thing I would do is understand what `weighty` and `weightx` are doing and how the affect the layout, I'd also look into the `anchor` property

Comment: I've tried playing around with weighty and weightx. It's either a 0 or 1. Even though it uses a double, results (of where the object is placed in the cell) are the same in between as if it equals a 1. The anchor seems to set it to the far edge of the cell (but no option for in between the edge of the cell and the center with a certain x/y layout). ipad (from what I could see) just controls the size of the object (will allow object to handle these permissions if left unset).

Comment: Do you understand what weightx/y does? Do you understand how it's applied across multiple components?

Comment: hmmm, from what I can read it basically sets the column sizes in the container. However since there are only two columns (as per the grid specifications when adding in the objects), the behavior will only be centered or to the edge. However, I am reading about insets, and I think this might have what I'm looking for (unsure as I have yet to play around with this).

Comment: The other option I'm thinking (other than trying out insets), is to add an empty box for additional end column (to force shrink the column sizes until they get down to what I want)

Comment: Based on your screenshot, you don't need weightx on the first column of components

Comment: Okay, I'll try setting weightx to 0. Also, I edited the code to add a setGbc method, and removed all the extra lines. So if we could look in this method and help me understand how it needs to be to look like the screen shot, it would be of much help. Also, after setting weightx to 0, it does not respect the anchor west input.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/141707/discussion-between-fiddle-freak-and-madprogrammer).

Comment: Tried seeing if you were there, but looks like you are afk. I tried removing weightx, and the column spaces are as they should be, however now both columns are centered. I need the columns to start at the west. Any idea how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`weightx` and `weighty` determine how much of the left over space is supplied to the given column/row.  If you supply a weightx/y value to two or more columns/rows, the space is divided between them, so, setting the `weightx` of column 1 and 2, like you have, means that they share 50% of the left of space, which is why it's looking the way it is.

Instead, only the last column really needs to have a `weightx` value at all

[image: Example]

```
selPane.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
selPane.setBorder(blackLine);

GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
gbc.gridx = 0;
gbc.gridy = 0;
gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;
gbc.insets = new Insets(2, 2, 2, 2);
charSelCombo.setPrototypeDisplayValue("Hello");
selPane.add(charSelCombo, gbc);
gbc.gridy++;
selPane.add(pickLvl, gbc);
gbc.gridy++;
selPane.add(nextLvl, gbc);

gbc.gridx = 1;
gbc.gridy = 1;
gbc.weightx = 1;
selPane.add(pickLvlAns, gbc);
gbc.gridy++;
selPane.add(nextLvlAns, gbc);
```

I simplified the code a little (for me).  One of the nice things about `GridBagConstraints` is, `GridBagLayout` will make a copy of the constraints you supply, so you can share it among multiple components, like I have above, it makes it easier to update and modify, as you maintain the overall relationship between the components

Comment: For some reason your code made it come out so everything was in 1 row. It also removed the empty pic space. I took your advice though in adding weightx 1 to the 2nd column. And this worked :) I edited the code above so you can see for yourself. I'm going to go ahead and mark you the answer, since you're suggestion of adding weghtx 1 to the 2nd column made it work (also, I understand how to use weights better now, basically shifting the favor of column/row size over the other). Thanks :)

Comment: Any chance of a reopen vote on [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/43415401/418556)? (See my comments there for justification.)